# Find multiple (all) shortest paths between a pair of vertices using Boost's Dijkstra shortest path implementation

Tags: c++, shortest-path, dijkstra, boost-graph

I have been using Boost to find the shortest paths (SP) between two nodes in a graph using their implementation of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm `dijkstra_shortest_paths`. This function returns a predecessor map that you can backtrack to get the SP from the target node. Despite this, the predecessor map does not account for the multiplicity of shortest paths.

I am calculating the shortest paths in a lattice (I know it is trivial but I need them for another thing) and my only option to get all the paths right now is to use Yen's algorithm. This solution is costly and, in theory, Dijkstra's algorithm is able to provide all SPs even with multiplicity.
I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068811/how-to-record-all-the-shortest-paths-from-a-source-vertex-to-a-destination-verte) but it is very old and maybe they have added some solution to the problem.

Does Boost have any solution for this?

**Edit**

Here is a sample code to calculate the SP using Dijkstra from boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/property_map/dynamic_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>


using namespace boost;

struct VertexProperties {
    int custom_index;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,                // OutEdgeList
    boost::vecS,                 // VertexList
    boost::undirectedS,          // UnDirected
    VertexProperties,     // VertexProperties
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> // EdgeProperties
> Graph;


typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;// descriptors for vertices and edges in the graph, allowing easy access to graph elements.
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
typedef std::pair<Vertex, Vertex> EdgePair;// This represents an edge as a pair of integers (vertex indices).
typedef std::vector<Vertex> Path;


int main() {

    /*
    
    READING CSV FILE: EDGE[0], EDGE[1], WEIGHT

    */

    Graph G(0);

    std::ifstream file("graph.csv");
    std::string line;
    std::getline(file, line);

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char>> tokens(line);
        auto tokenIterator = tokens.begin();
        int vertex1 = std::stoi(*tokenIterator++);
        int vertex2 = std::stoi(*tokenIterator++);
        double weight = std::stod(*tokenIterator);
        // Add edge to the graph with the given weight
        Edge e = add_edge(vertex1, vertex2, G).first;
        put(edge_weight, G, e, weight);
    }

    /*
    
    END OF READ
    
    */

std::size_t numVertices = std::distance(boost::vertices(G).first, boost::vertices(G).second);

Path predecessors(numVertices);
std::vector<double> distances(numVertices);
        
dijkstra_shortest_paths(G, 0,
                        predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(predecessors.begin(), get(vertex_index, G)))
                        .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(), get(vertex_index, G))));


// Reconstruct the Shortest path
std::vector<int> shortestP;
int currentNode = 80;

while (currentNode != 0) {

    shortestP.push_back(currentNode);
    if (predecessors[currentNode] == currentNode) {// target node not accessible
        shortestP.clear();
        break;
    }
    currentNode = predecessors[currentNode];
}
shortestP.push_back(0);

for (int i = 0; i < shortestP.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << shortestP[i];
    if (i < shortestP.size() - 1) {
        std::cout << " -> ";
    }

}
}
```

This code reads a Graph from a csv file easily generated with networkx:

```
import csv
import networkx as nx
def write_graph_to_csv(G, filename = 'graph.csv'):
    # Open a CSV file in write mode
    with open(filename, 
              'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        # Create a CSV writer object
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    
        # Write the header row (optional)
        csvwriter.writerow(['vertex1', 'vertex2', 'edge_weight'])
    
        # Write edges and their weights to the CSV file
        for u, v, weight in G.edges(data='length'):
            csvwriter.writerow([u, v, weight])

    print('Graph has been written to graph.csv')

N = 9
graph = nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N,periodic=False)
pos = {i: j for i,j in enumerate(graph.nodes)}
labels = {i: k for k, i in enumerate(graph.nodes)}
nx.relabel_nodes(graph, labels, copy=False)
print(graph.nodes)
nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 10)
edge_lens = {edge: np.linalg.norm(np.array(pos[edge[1]]) - 
np.array(pos[edge[0]])) for edge in graph.edges}

nx.set_edge_attributes(graph, edge_lens, name = 'length')
write_graph_to_csv(graph)
```

The expected result would be all the shortest paths but I only get one:

Output:

```
80 -> 71 -> 70 -> 69 -> 68 -> 67 -> 58 -> 57 -> 56 -> 55 -> 54 -> 45 -> 36 -> 27 -> 18 -> 9 -> 0
```

Comment: Do edges have weights? If so are they never negative? (What would help most is a sample graph and expected output)

Comment: Yes, positive weights. In my case it is a 3x3 lattice with all edges with weight 1.

Comment: Oh... that simplifies. Because Dijkstra just becomes BFS with unity weights. I've just answered the more general case, I'm sure you can simplify it down to constant weights.

Comment: There could be exponentially many shortest paths.

Comment: I find that Yen's algorithm works well.  It doesn't seem cripplingly "costly".  How big are your graphs?  What is your performance requirement?  Some documentation on how I use Yen at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/All-Paths

Comment: @sehe that's fine, I needed a more general version for other types of graphs, thanks!

Comment: @RobertBenassai In that case, pre-empting the inevitable head-scratches when using something other than `vecS` as the container selectors: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47a589f078010d13 (or without the tracing and just iostream: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8edf374c31693c3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume a sample directed graph

[image]

There are two paths from zero to three, having equal weight (1+5+7+3 == 1+12+3 == 16). However, the naive would only result in the first-discovered predecessor being recorded:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14a9ed0e0413e0c5)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, struct VProps, struct EProps>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;

using Weight = double;
struct VProps { std::string name = "unnamed"; };
struct EProps { Weight weight = 0; };

void render(G& g) {
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", get(&VProps::name, g));
    dp.property("label",   get(&EProps::weight, g));
    dp.property("rankdir", boost::make_constant_property<G*>(+"LR"));

    std::ofstream ofs("graph.dot");
    write_graphviz_dp(ofs, g, dp);
    system("/usr/bin/dot -Tpng -o dot.png graph.dot");
}

int main() {
    G g(5);
    auto vidx   = get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    auto name   = get(&VProps::name, g);
    auto weight = get(&EProps::weight, g);
    name[0]     = "A";
    name[1]     = "B";
    name[2]     = "C";
    name[3]     = "D";
    name[4]     = "E";

    add_edge(0, 4, {1},  g);
    add_edge(4, 1, {5},  g);
    add_edge(4, 2, {12}, g);
    add_edge(1, 2, {7},  g);
    add_edge(2, 3, {3},  g);

    render(g);

    std::vector<Weight> dist(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<V>      pred(num_vertices(g));

    dijkstra_shortest_paths(                                                        //
        g, 0,                                                                       //
        weight_map(weight)                                                          //
            .distance_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(dist.begin(), vidx))    //
            .predecessor_map(boost::make_iterator_property_map(pred.begin(), vidx)) //
    );

    fmt::print("distances:    {}\n", dist);
    fmt::print("predecessors: {}\n", pred);
}
```

Printing

```
distances:    [0, 6, 13, 16, 1]
predecessors: [0, 4, 4, 2, 0]
```

### Tweaking The Predecessors

Now you can use the default `distance` recording, but you want to be smarter about the predecessors. You'd like to use e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::set<V>> pred(num_vertices(g));
```

That however doesn't work by default. So you can tweak it using your own visitor that records the predecessors instead:

```
struct vis_t : default_dijkstra_visitor {
    state& s;
    vis_t(state& s) : s(s) {}

    void edge_relaxed(E e, G const& g) const {
        s.pred[target(e, g)] = {source(e, g)};
    }
    void edge_not_relaxed(E e, G const& g) const {
        // e: u -> v
        auto u = source(e, g);
        auto v = target(e, g);

        auto old  = s.dist[v];
        auto new_ = s.dist[u] + g[e].weight;

        if (std::nextafter(new_, old) == old) {
            s.pred[v].insert(u);
        }
    }
} vis{s};
```

> *Note that comparison if floating point numbers is trickier, see [How do you compare float and double while accounting for precision loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/how-do-you-compare-float-and-double-while-accounting-for-precision-loss) and [How to correctly and standardly compare floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548004/how-to-correctly-and-standardly-compare-floats/35252934#35252934)*

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffd55417de17ef24)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, struct VProps, struct EProps>;
using V = G::vertex_descriptor;
using E = G::edge_descriptor;

using Weight = double;
struct VProps { std::string name = "unnamed"; };
struct EProps { Weight weight = 0; };

int main() {
    for (Weight alternative_weight : {6, 7, 8}) {
        G    g(5);
        auto vidx   = get(boost::vertex_index, g);
        auto name   = get(&VProps::name, g);
        auto weight = get(&EProps::weight, g);
        name[0]     = "A";
        name[1]     = "B";
        name[2]     = "C";
        name[3]     = "D";
        name[4]     = "E";

        add_edge(0, 4, {1}, g);
        add_edge(4, 1, {5}, g);
        add_edge(4, 2, {12}, g);
        add_edge(1, 2, {alternative_weight}, g);
        add_edge(2, 3, {3}, g);

        struct state {
            G&                       g;
            std::vector<Weight>      dist;
            std::vector<std::set<V>> pred;
            state(G& g) : g(g), dist(num_vertices(g)), pred(num_vertices(g)) {}
        } s(g);

        struct vis_t : boost::default_dijkstra_visitor {
            state& s;
            vis_t(state& s) : s(s) {}

            void edge_relaxed(E e, G const& g) const {
                s.pred[target(e, g)] = {source(e, g)};
            }
            void edge_not_relaxed(E e, G const& g) const {
                // e: u -> v
                auto u = source(e, g);
                auto v = target(e, g);

                auto old  = s.dist[v];
                auto new_ = s.dist[u] + g[e].weight;

                if (std::nextafter(new_, old) == old)
                    s.pred[v].insert(u);
            }
        } vis{s};

        dijkstra_shortest_paths(                                                //
            g, 0,                                                               //
            weight_map(weight)                                                  //
                .visitor(vis)                                                   //
                .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(s.dist.begin(), vidx)) //
        );

        fmt::print("distances:    {}\n", s.dist);
        fmt::print("predecessors: {}\n", s.pred);
    }
}
```

Printing

```
distances:    [0, 6, 12, 15, 1]
predecessors: [{}, {4}, {1}, {2}, {0}]
distances:    [0, 6, 13, 16, 1]
predecessors: [{}, {4}, {1, 4}, {2}, {0}]
distances:    [0, 6, 13, 16, 1]
predecessors: [{}, {4}, {4}, {2}, {0}]
```

Or with full event tracing **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d8c4efdf49cbaa3)**:

```
           INIT A@0  , dist: [0  , 0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT B@0  , dist: [inf, 0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT C@0  , dist: [inf, inf, 0  , 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT D@0  , dist: [inf, inf, inf, 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT E@0  , dist: [inf, inf, inf, inf, 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
       DISCOVER A@0  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, inf], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
        EXAMINE A@0  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, inf], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
        EXAMINE edge 0->4 weight 1
        RELAXED edge 0->4 weight 1
       DISCOVER E@1  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {0}]
         FINISH A@0  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE E@1  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 4->1 weight 5
        RELAXED edge 4->1 weight 5
       DISCOVER B@6  , dist: [0  , 6  , inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 4->2 weight 12
        RELAXED edge 4->2 weight 12
       DISCOVER C@13 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
         FINISH E@1  , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE B@6  , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 1->2 weight 6
        RELAXED edge 1->2 weight 6
         FINISH B@6  , dist: [0  , 6  , 12 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE C@12 , dist: [0  , 6  , 12 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 2->3 weight 3
        RELAXED edge 2->3 weight 3
       DISCOVER D@15 , dist: [0  , 6  , 12 , 15 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1}, {2}, {0}]
         FINISH C@12 , dist: [0  , 6  , 12 , 15 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1}, {2}, {0}]
        EXAMINE D@15 , dist: [0  , 6  , 12 , 15 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1}, {2}, {0}]
         FINISH D@15 , dist: [0  , 6  , 12 , 15 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1}, {2}, {0}]
distances:    [0, 6, 12, 15, 1]
predecessors: [{}, {4}, {1}, {2}, {0}]
           INIT A@0  , dist: [0  , 0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT B@0  , dist: [inf, 0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT C@0  , dist: [inf, inf, 0  , 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT D@0  , dist: [inf, inf, inf, 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT E@0  , dist: [inf, inf, inf, inf, 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
       DISCOVER A@0  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, inf], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
        EXAMINE A@0  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, inf], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
        EXAMINE edge 0->4 weight 1
        RELAXED edge 0->4 weight 1
       DISCOVER E@1  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {0}]
         FINISH A@0  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE E@1  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 4->1 weight 5
        RELAXED edge 4->1 weight 5
       DISCOVER B@6  , dist: [0  , 6  , inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 4->2 weight 12
        RELAXED edge 4->2 weight 12
       DISCOVER C@13 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
         FINISH E@1  , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE B@6  , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 1->2 weight 7
     NOTRELAXED edge 1->2 weight 7
    ALTERNATIVE edge 1->2 weight 7
         FINISH B@6  , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1, 4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE C@13 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1, 4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 2->3 weight 3
        RELAXED edge 2->3 weight 3
       DISCOVER D@16 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , 16 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1, 4}, {2}, {0}]
         FINISH C@13 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , 16 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1, 4}, {2}, {0}]
        EXAMINE D@16 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , 16 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1, 4}, {2}, {0}]
         FINISH D@16 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , 16 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {1, 4}, {2}, {0}]
distances:    [0, 6, 13, 16, 1]
predecessors: [{}, {4}, {1, 4}, {2}, {0}]
           INIT A@0  , dist: [0  , 0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT B@0  , dist: [inf, 0  , 0  , 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT C@0  , dist: [inf, inf, 0  , 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT D@0  , dist: [inf, inf, inf, 0  , 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
           INIT E@0  , dist: [inf, inf, inf, inf, 0  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
       DISCOVER A@0  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, inf], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
        EXAMINE A@0  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, inf], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
        EXAMINE edge 0->4 weight 1
        RELAXED edge 0->4 weight 1
       DISCOVER E@1  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {0}]
         FINISH A@0  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE E@1  , dist: [0  , inf, inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 4->1 weight 5
        RELAXED edge 4->1 weight 5
       DISCOVER B@6  , dist: [0  , 6  , inf, inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 4->2 weight 12
        RELAXED edge 4->2 weight 12
       DISCOVER C@13 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
         FINISH E@1  , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE B@6  , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 1->2 weight 8
     NOTRELAXED edge 1->2 weight 8
         FINISH B@6  , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE C@13 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , inf, 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {}, {0}]
        EXAMINE edge 2->3 weight 3
        RELAXED edge 2->3 weight 3
       DISCOVER D@16 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , 16 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {2}, {0}]
         FINISH C@13 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , 16 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {2}, {0}]
        EXAMINE D@16 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , 16 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {2}, {0}]
         FINISH D@16 , dist: [0  , 6  , 13 , 16 , 1  ], pred: [{}, {4}, {4}, {2}, {0}]
distances:    [0, 6, 13, 16, 1]
predecessors: [{}, {4}, {4}, {2}, {0}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solves the issue! @sehe

Comment: Just [fixed a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77375620/revisions) that would also record alternatives on relaxing existing vertex... Also in the unity weights version: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/289cc1cc6a82d23b